# Ordinary linear regression vs penalized regression: predictive MSE

Tags: regression, lasso, ridge-regression, mse, regularization

Does predicting on a test set with an ordinary linear regression model result in a smaller predictive MSE compared to a penalized regression model (LASSO or ridge)?

Comment: if that were the case, why would we have Lasso or Ridge?

Comment: I was under the impression that using ridge reduces the variance of the estimates

Comment: That is correct, but that will also increase the bias. The goal is to minimize the MSE by adding a little bias and reducing the variability substantially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLS can be considered a special case of penalized regression where the penalty strength is zero.  In this context, we choose the penalty strength in an attempt to minimize generalization (predictive) error, using cross validation.  In this sense, we generally expect penalized regression to have superior predictive strength.